# The code install-wolfram-engine-13.3.1.sh fails with dependency errors on Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) on Pi4

Tags: raspberry-pi, free-wolfram-engine

should the install script work as it is or are there any prerequisites for it to work?

TIA

Comment: I was able to install MMA 13.3.1 on the 64-bit version of RaspiOS 11 (Bullseye) using `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wolfram-engine`.

Comment: @LouisB thanks, that worked nicely.